# How to swap the ImageView height and width in xml

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-xml, android-bitmap

I have an ImageView in my xml like this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivMessage"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/two_hundred_dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/one_sixty_dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/ten_dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle_white"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:padding="@dimen/ten_dp"
    tools:src="@drawable/logo" />
```

but the photos I am getting from the server can be in portrait and landscape mode, I just want to swap this height and width when something like this occured. I have tried to convert those dp programaticaly but this doesnt work and the dp got changed. Is there any simple way I am missing?

Comment: do the dimensions have to be 200,160 in every image?

Comment: Yes, but those values are different for different screen size like 200 for sw600 is 300 and for sw720 is 400

Comment: Have you tried `wrap_content`? What's the problem using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said image that comes from server can either be portrait or in landscape, here is what you can do to swipe the dimensions programmatically.

**Step 1. Determine if the image is landscape or portrait**

```
boolean landscape = false;

if(image.getHeight()>image.getWidth()){
//image is in portrait
landscape = false;
}else{
//image is in landscape
landscape = true;
}
```

**Step 2. Change height and width accordingly**

```
if(landscape){
imageView.setWidth(200);
imageView.setHeight(160);
}
else{
imageView.setWidth(160);
imageView.setHeight(200);
}
```

Comment: I exactly did the same before seeing your answer, thank a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

use android:adjustViewBounds and maxHeight or minHeight attributes like this:

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivMessage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:maxWidth="@dimen/two_hundred_dp"
                android:maxHeight="@dimen/one_sixty_dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/ten_dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle_white"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:padding="@dimen/ten_dp"
                tools:src="@drawable/logo" />
```